# how to add limit in cakephp having joins

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.3

following is my code to fetch record from table

```
    $joins=array(
            array(
                'table' => 'users',
                'alias' => 'User',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.id= Notification.UserId'
                )
            )
    );
    // fetching all records
    $returnArray = $this->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Notification.id','User.Name'),
        'joins' =>  $joins,
        'order' => 'Notification.id DESC',
        'limit'=>'100',
    ));
```

In above code my limit is not working coz i am using joins. can anybody tell me how to use limit with joins in cakephp.
Is there any other method to add limit? PLease tell me ASAP
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Cake, but try an integer instead of string with your limit.

```
$returnArray = $this->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Notification.id','User.Name'),
        'joins' =>  $joins,
        'order' => 'Notification.id DESC',
        'limit'=> 100,
));
```